# Using SQL Server Management Studio to run a Job to make an API Call instead of a SQL Procedure

Tags: sql-server, api, rest, soap, sql-job

Is there a way schedule a job in SQL Server management studio to make API calls (SOAP or REST) directly from SQL Server.

Where can I find more rules/syntax etc to do this. I need to make API calls on a schedule (nightly). These API calls will do a combination of things but I'd like to call them from the Server Job set up directly.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use SSIS package and if it does not have built in functionality you can write C# script task to do it.

Comment: If you mean from a SQL Agent job rather than the SQL Server database engine, you could also use PowerShell.